# charging super-capacitor with cosntant current

Tags: supercapacitor

I want to charge a super-capacitor with a LiIon charger circuit like this one
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/472/AAT3693_201896C-533711.pdf

Basically, capacitor is 50F (2 x 100F in series) and will be charged with constant current until 4.2V. I am not sure I calculate right the charge time, based on this:
[Calculate charge time of a capacitor through a current limiting power supply?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60245/calculate-charge-time-of-a-capacitor-through-a-current-limiting-power-supply)

```
Q = C * U = 50 * 4.2 = 210
t = Q / Ilim = 210 / 1.6A = 131.25s = 2.1875 minutes
```

For deep discharge (thanks @jms) will be 10% of current (0.16A) until trickle threshold (2.9V) enforced by charger. This will yields to 15 minutes according my calculations. (correct?)

Thank you

Comment: Be aware that li-ion charger ICs (including the one you linked) either refuse to charge or only perform a very low current trickle charge if the battery voltage is below a minimum threshold unsafe for the battery (e.g. 2.8 V). If you cannot disable this functionality, your supercap will only really charge if the voltage is above that threshold. Your math is correct, but won't apply to li-ion chargers for this reason.

Comment: I forgot about this, see edited, thank you. But calculation is reasonable?

Comment: Everything seems OK. I would use some switching circuit to keep power on the charger low. I mean, anyway your capacitor is not very cheap, so if it's not a very mass production, instead saving money go for best solution. Ah, for supercap in series balancing circuits may be required.

Comment: There are versions of AAT3693 without trickle charge so that 15min should be avoided. @Gregory Kornblum, I don't understand keeping power low. I will use minimum specified Vin (5V5) for minimum dissipated power during heavily charge. It is not a mass production but must be safe and maintenance free. I guess supercaps outperforms LiIon but of course, about 4x price of brand battery.

Comment: The device you mentioned has low efficiency, hence you loose power and heat the device. Same function may be done by a switching device with 90% efficiency. And ut ia more fun.